# Discovering a function in two variables involved in a system of equations

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, functional-equations

I have a problem in which I need to discover $f$ knowing that $$\left\{\begin{matrix}f(1,y)-f(0,y)=y\\f(x,1)-f(x,0)=x\end{matrix}\right.$$ Any hints to solve it?

Comment: How do you define "solve"? There is absolutely no hope of finding $f(x,y)$ unless either $x$ or $y$ is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I have edited my question right now, sorry.

Comment: What are the conditions on the function $f$? What is the domain of $f$?  This function $f$ would be  with the property of being continuous, smooth or analytic?

Comment: Then I will repeat what I said: there is no way to use those equations to find $f(2,2)$. So unless $x$ and $y$ are limited to $\{0,1\}$ or you have some similarly strict constraint on $f$ there is little that can be done.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ can only take values $0$ and $1$. And $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Assume $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$. Take continuous $f$ (in fact you can prove it). Note that for all $\alpha,\beta \in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\beta f(1, y)-\beta f(0, y)=\beta y, \\ 
\alpha f( x,1)- \alpha f( x,0)=\alpha x
\end{matrix}\right.
\Leftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 f(1, \beta y)- f(0, \beta y)=\beta y, \\ 
 f( \alpha x,1)-  f( \alpha x,0)=\alpha x
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Ask yourself if the function $f$ is a quadratic form added to affine function:
$$
f(x,y)= 
\begin{pmatrix}x & y\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} M_{11} & M_{12}\\ M_{21} & M_{22}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}V_1 & V_2\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}+C
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can't solve this equation with the amount of information given, but yes:

If we let $f(x,y) = xy$, then certainly $f(x,1)-f(x,0) = x-0=x$ and $f(1,y)-f(0,y) = y - 0 = y$, so this is one solution.

Comment: and how do you know that $$f(x,y)=xy$$?

Comment: Guess. Just a guess.